# Where in the world is my pandoc directory?

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to add a custom latex template for pandoc

I know that pandoc templates go in `~/.pandoc/templates`

and I confirmed the pandoc directory location by typing `pandoc --v` - it says pandoc is in `~/.pandoc`

but when I do `cd ~/.pandoc`:

```
-bash: cd: /Users/[Name]/.pandoc: No such file or directory
```

According the pandoc man page I can set a different path for pandoc data files using `--data-dir=DIRECTORY`, but when I try build a file this way, e.g.

```
pandoc file.md -o file.pdf --data-dir=~/Library/texmf/tex/latex --template=mytemplate.latex
```

it throws the error

```
pandoc: Could not find data file templates/mytemplate.latex
```

which I assume means the data directory command is ignored.

Why can't I access my pandoc directory?

Comment: How about creating the expected directory? `mkdir ~/.pandoc` Maybe you are using a non-standard shell that doesn't understand `~`, try using `$HOME` in place of `~` maybe.

Comment: ~ works fine - for example ~/.jupyter takes me to jupyter

Comment: In "Pandoc User's Guide" see `--data-dir=DIRECTORY` in the Options section. It says: "*(Note that the user data directory is not created by pandoc, so you will need to create it yourself if you want to make use of it.)*"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are indeed expected to create the `~/.pandoc` directory if it doesn't exist already. For example for a default latex template:

```
mkdir -p ~/.pandoc/templates
pandoc -D latex > ~/.pandoc/templates/default.latex
```

The `--template` option looks for files relative to the current directory (`pwd`), or "if not found, pandoc will search for it in the templates subdirectory of the user data directory" (`~/.pandoc/templates` for `--data-dir=~/.pandoc`, which is the default).

Which is where your error comes from as there's probably no file `/Library/texmf/tex/latex/templates/mytemplate.latex`.

Comment: whoah, I assumed that the directory already existed. why would I have to create it when it says it exists? anyway, creating the directory and putting the template inside worked fine. However, I still don't understand the directory direction problem. The template was indeed inside that path.

Comment: @cmc `mkdir ~/.pandoc/templates` gives `.pandoc: No such file or directory` in my macOS terminal, so that doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: @mb21 Did you edit out the -p? mkdir -p ~/.pandoc/templates