# Pandoc user data directory

Tags: templates, pandoc

I want to use a custom latex template with Pandoc.

I followed the [instructions](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-options) (--data-dir) but then I couldn't find the user data directory on my mac as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706967/where-in-the-world-is-my-pandoc-directory).

So I created the .pandoc/templates folders manually, put my template inside `~/.pandoc/templates`, run `pandoc input.md --template=mytemplate.latex -o output.pdf`

and this is what I get

```
pandoc: Could not find data file /usr/local/Cellar/pandoc/1.18/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.1/pandoc-1.18/data/templates/mytemplate.latex
```

I could easily move my template inside that folder but I'm quite sure that's not the right way, if only for the fact that it would stop working as soon as I upgrade to v.1.19.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved. For some reason it couldn't read my template file.

Instead I've edited the template that `pandoc -D latex > ~/.pandoc/templates/default.latex` generated and renamed it to mytemplate.latex.

It's working now.